# TeamCity conflict with % symbol in Command Line build step

Tags: teamcity

I have a batch file that I use to copy a folder and it's contents to a new location, it also creates the folder name based on the date and time (and this works):

```
SET TODAY=%DATE:/=-%
SET NOW=%TIME::=-%
XCOPY /S /Y "C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp" "C:\Automation Results\%TODAY%_%NOW%\"
```

I added a new Configuration Step to my Team City setup, to include this batch file. The build step is a Command Line - Custom Script:

[image: Build Step]

But this has an adverse effect on the TC Agent Requirements and I cannot start my TC builds:

[image: Agent Requirements]

This issue seems to be related to TC Implicit Requirements:

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Agent+Requirements

"Implicit Requirements
Any reference (name in %-signs) to an unknown parameter is considered an "implicit requirement". That means that the build will only run on the agent which provides the parameters named. Otherwise, the parameter should be made available for the build configuration by defining it on the build configuration or project levels."

How can I get around this TC conflict with % symbol which I need in my batch file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `%%` instead of `%`

```
SET TODAY=%%DATE:/=-%%
SET NOW=%%TIME::=-%%
XCOPY /S /Y "C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp" "C:\Automation Results\%%TODAY%%_%%NOW%%\"
```

This will ensure the variables are treated as batch file variables instead of TeamCity variables.

Comment: Nice tip. This does indeed ensure the variables are treated as batch file variables instead of TeamCity variables.

Comment: and if you by any chance need to use FOR loop and operate on file in folder, and need to use double-percent sign, then you'll need to put four of them instead of two. Example can be like this:  FOR /D %%%%f in (%system.teamcity.build.workingDir%\path\to\folder\*) do xcopy "%%%%f\*.*" "path\to\other\folder\%%%%~nf_blah.%build.counter%" /Q /E /I

Answer (score 3):

put the contents of your build script inside a file, eg copy.bat and call this batch file from TeamCity

Addtionally, change from `Custom script` to `Executable with parameters`

[image]

Comment: Correct you are! The easy solution was just to add the batch file to my project and call it from that location via TeamCity.

Comment: this also has the advantage of having the batch file in source control